# Organizing an saas project

Tags: continuous-integration, project-management, saas

I am leading a SaaS application. Let's say it is a java data analysis system delivered over Rest API. I have several developers, and we use

- a repository (e.g. git, hg, say on bitbucket or github),
- scrum agile workflow (using e.g.  jira agile, youtrack),
- continuous integration (e.g. jenkins, bamboo)
- maven

I am wondering what are the best practices (and pros/cons) in splitting the big project  into subprojects (if at all).

Generally, I can see the following logical modules:

- rest interface
- DataAnalytics API (no implementation)
- ranking modules: Module1, Module2, ..
- categorization modules: Module1, Module2
- visualization
- etc

Do I want to make it one big repository with several subprojects? But then

- I need to keep track of versions, and
- make sure that the CI server builds only the relevant subproject when something is committed (I probably do not want to build and retest the rest interface when a categorization module is updated)

Or do I want to make one repository for each project?

Any other possibilities/things I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I want to make it one big repository with several subprojects?

This is often debated topic. Some of your requirements based on your questions below can help determine.

> ```
> I need to keep track of versions, and
> ```

Can your services be deployed and versioned differently ie. can you keep running service A with version x and then deploy a fix to service B with version y, without changes to service A. If so, keeping them in separate repositories helps.

> make sure that the CI server builds only the relevant subproject when
>   something is committed > (I probably do not want to build and retest
>   the rest interface when a categorization module is updated)

Again, this is one reason for not bundling everything into one repository. You do not want changes to visualization to require a rebuild of rest API. So they are candidates for separate repos. This also helps sub teams and distributed teams.

But, if the code base and team size is too small, it may be an overhead to split into too many repos.